# puppet ssl failed with message "unknown ca"

Tags: ssl, puppet

I've tried to build a master/agent system with puppet.
My master host name is snspay.cn, I followed the document, and everything was right until I tried to get the catalog from the master. My command is

```
puppet agent --server snspay.cn --no-daemonize --test onetime --verbose
```

and the output from the agent

```
Error: Could not request certificate: SSL_connect returned=1 
errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify
failed: [self signed certificate in certificate chain for /CN=Puppet
CA: snspay.cn]
```

and the master's log is like

```
[2014-08-11 14:39:14] ERROR OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_accept 
returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read client certificate A: tlsv1 
alert unknown ca
```

I think it is wrong with the ssl instead of puppet it self, but I'm not very familiar with ssl, any ideas?

---

well I have added another agent node(ubuntu) with a total different environment and everything is so well, so the problems is with the original agent node, I am now running `yum update` in that node and try later

Comment: Please update the question with the certificate. Use `openssl x509 -in <cert> -text -noout`. Or, you could use `openssl s_client -connect snspay.cn:443 -servername snspay.cn | openssl x509 -text -noout`.

Comment: Is the clock on the failing agent in sync with that of the master?

Comment: The clock on the agent is 12 hours later than the master, I changed it as the master and everything is right. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your agent has not established trust with the master.

What basically needs to happen is for the agent to import the master's CA certificate to the agent. However, since the agent's cert is obviously signed by an obsolete CA, you will have to replace **all** SSL data.

On the agent, find the `$ssldir` (usually `/var/lib/puppet/ssl`) using

```
puppet agent --configprint ssldir
```

and rename or remove it.

Upon the next `puppet agent --test` run, the agent should request a new certificate, and cache th correct CA.

Comment: I've already done this. Every time I gave a new try, I would remove all the files in $ssldir in both master and agent.